# Flex 4 css cheat sheet

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, styles

Is there any cheat sheet or something similar that shows me all the Flex 4 CSS styles available?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/More+Styles+for+Spark+Skins

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried using the defaults.css in your sdk folder of you flash builder install folder?

Should be under /sdks/4.0.0/frameworks/projects/framework

Just reading through and searching this file is the fastest way (for me, at least) to find out how the component is getting styled by default, and what to change for custom styles when skinning.

Comment: Nice! The airframework also has some info.

Answer (score 0):

It is specific to the component you're trying to style.  So, I'd check out the ASDocs of the component in question.